# Display search result inside customized div tag using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am working on a search page where I am getting the input from the user and then using PHP, I am connecting to a database, executing a query and trying to display the results on the page. I need to display the result in a div tag where I need various search results to be displayed.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test1"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="postjob"; // Table name

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$dbconn = mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name) or die(mysql_error());
echo $dbconn;
echo "Connected to Database<br />";

$output = '';
$keywords=$_POST['keywords']; 
$location=$_POST['location'];

$keywords = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $keywords);
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $location);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE job_title LIKE '%$keywords%' OR job_type     
LIKE '%$keywords%' OR job_category LIKE '%$keywords%' OR job_tags LIKE  
'%$keywords%' OR description LIKE '%$keywords%' OR company_name LIKE 
'%$keywords%' OR location LIKE'%$location%'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Sign Up</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <section class="content_area">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class ="result">
        <table>
          <tr>
             <?php 
             while($jobsearch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>"."<h3>".$jobsearch['job_title']."</h3>"." 
             <br>".$jobsearch['company_name']."<br>".$jobsearch['description']."</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
            }

             ?>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
   </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I am calling the above PHP file using post action from HTML form page which has Keywords and location textbox. I am fetching job_title, company_name and description from Database and displaying it. Here I am using a table to display. But I wanted use a div where I need to do some styling. I tried to use below code replacing table with div, but it is not displaying any result.

```
<?php 
while($jobsearch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<div>"."<h3>".$jobsearch['job_title']."</h3>"." 
<br>".$jobsearch['company_name']."<br>".$jobsearch['description'].      
</div>";
}
?>
```

I am expecting result like below inside a div

```
job_title
company_name
description
<button>Apply</button>
```

I tried the below code, but it is not displaying any result.

```
<?php
  while($jobsearch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<div><h3>".$jobsearch['job_title']."</h3></div>
   <div>".$jobsearch['company_name']."</div>
   <div>".$jobsearch['description']. "</div>";
  }
 ?>
```

I need to customize this div to do some styling. Could someone help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class ="result">
        <table>
             <?php 
             while($jobsearch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>"."<h3>".$jobsearch['job_title']."</h3></td>"; 
             echo "</tr>";
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>"."<h3>".$jobsearch['company_name']."</h3></td>";
             echo "</tr>";             
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>"."<h3>".$jobsearch['description']."</h3></td>";
             echo "</tr>";                 
            echo "<br />";
            }
             ?>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting the result using table. But I want result inside a div tag where I need to customize the div using some styling.

Comment: I can include button inside another <tr> statement?

Comment: It is throwing an error at the end of first </tr> statement when I use the above code

Comment: sorry, my bad. Now try that code. It should work as expected. Thanks

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, your code displays the result in 3 different rows. But I want to display all results in a single row. Probably using a div tag.

Comment: You didn't mention in your question anywhere that you want to "omit" the use of HTML `tables` in your code.

Comment: If you could look at my question one more time, I have mentioned that I need to replace table with div tag and I would have also mentioned about the expected result which I need inside div tag.

Comment: Do you think you can later on edit any of your post and think that none else will be able to see the changes? You added the lines for replacing your table with div later on.

Comment: I am sorry if you took me that way. Please do check the last update made and the corresponding timing, it doesn't show my name. And there are no updates made by me after all your reply!!!.. Also, please see the other reply here. There were suggestions for using div and those replies were made at same time as you replied and that was my initial question. Thanks for your time!!!..

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work.

```
<ul>
 <?php
  while($jobsearch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<li>"."<h3>".$jobsearch['job_title']."</h3>"."</li>" 
   echo "<li>"."<h3>".$jobsearch['company_name']."</h3>"."</li>" 
   echo "<li>"."<h3>".$jobsearch['description']."</h3>"."</li>"
   echo "<button>Apply</button>";
  }
 ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should throw an error as " is missing in your echo statement
try this

```
echo "<div><h3>".$jobsearch['job_title']."</h3></div>
        <div>".$jobsearch['company_name']."</div>
        <div>".$jobsearch['description']. "</div>";
```

attached is the output, this output is by replacing your variables with some defined values

[image]

Comment: updated my answer, attached the output that i had, whats the error for you

Comment: I updated my question at the end with the code suggested by you. When I used that, it is not displaying any result.

Comment: are you getting your result in $jobsearch? if you have your array values then it will surely print

Comment: yeah, my result is available in the variable $jobsearch, if u see my question, there I used a table to display, when I use that I am getting the result displayed on screen, but when I change it to div, it is not displaying any result.

Comment: Can you please post the entire code snippet which you used?